# LinkLabel accessibility problem in WinForms application

Tags: winforms, accessibility, nvda

I am working on a windows application and trying to improve accessibility. Using NVDA screen reader to verify.

Problem is the `LinkLabel` controls are reported two times **while navigating with TAB key**. So, I decided to set `AccessibleRole` to `None`. But this time NVDA sometimes announces the controls two times. (Greens are one time; yellows are two times.)

[image: nvda-inconsistent-reporting]

I wonder is there anybody has any idea or solution regarding to this problem. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Looks normal to me.  LinkLabel indeed has two automatable properties, the label (text) and the clickable shortcut (link).  Hard to guarantee with the mouse to hit one but not the other.

Comment: Is it also possible while navigating with TAB key? @HansPassant